# Multiplication operator with or without braces

Tags: arduino-uno

I have written a simple calculator program for an LCD keypad shield. It works fine except for the multiplication case. It gives me zero. However, I have noticed that when I enclose the expression num1 * num2 in parenthesis it does work. Why is that so?

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd (8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7);


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.clear();
}

void loop() {

  float ans = 0;

  lcd.print("Starting Calc");
  delay(500);

  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Enter 1st Num");
  while (Serial.available() == 0) {}
  float num1 = Serial.parseFloat();

  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Enter 2nd Num");
  while (Serial.available () == 0) {}
  float num2 = Serial.parseFloat();

  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Enter Operator");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(" R+, U*, D/, L- ");
  int val = analogRead(A0);

  while (val > 1000) {
    val = analogRead(A0);
  }

  if (val == 0) { // addition
    ans = num1 + num2;
  }

  if (val >= 97 && val <= 98) { // multiplication
    ans = num1 * num2;
  }

  if (val >= 253 && val <= 254) { // division
    ans = num1 / num2;
  }

  if (val >= 407 && val <= 408) { // subtraction
    ans = num1 - num2;
  }

    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Answer is = ");
    lcd.print(ans);
    delay(2000);
}
```

---

### Modified Code

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd (8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.clear();
}

void loop() {

  float ans = 0.0;

  lcd.print("Starting Calc");
  delay(500);

  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Enter 1st Num");
  while (Serial.available() == 0) {}
  float num1 = Serial.parseFloat();

  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Enter 2nd Num");
  while (Serial.available () == 0) {}
  float num2 = Serial.parseFloat();

  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Enter Operator");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(" R+, U*, D/, L- ");

  // here we split our logic.. first repeatedly read input value until valid operator read
  // secondly we perform the arithmetic operation accordingly

  char input = ' '; // space = no operator read so far
  int val;

  do {
    val = analogRead(A0);
    // see how if statements are written concisely for readability
    // if only one statement after condition you can skip curly brackets
    if (val == 0) input = '+';
    if (val >= 97 && val <= 98) input = '*';
    if (val >= 253 && val <= 254) input = '/';
    if (val >= 407 && val <= 408) input = '-';
  } while (input == ' ');

  Serial.println(input);
  Serial.println(num1);
  Serial.println(num2);
  delay(1000);


  // perform arithmetic operation
    switch (val) { // not written in a standard way but very readable
      case '+': ans = num1 + num2; break;
      case '-': ans = num1 - num2; break;
      case '*': ans = num1 * num2; break;
      case '/': ans = num1 / num2; break;
    }

  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Answer = ");
  lcd.print(ans);
  delay(2000);
}
```

Comment: I think you're looking in the wrong place. The brackets make no difference. Instead you should be looking at your usage of parseFloat.

Comment: I also don't think that brackets don't make a difference. However, I don't see any problem with my usage of parseFloat. It seems to work for other operations. Do you see an issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parentheses should definitely make no difference. My guess is that
what you saw was just a coincidence. The analog ranges you have defined
are extremely narrow. Any instability in the circuit can throw your
readings out of the expected ranges. If you get a reading that does not
fit in any of those ranges, none of the `if` conditions will evaluate to
`true`, and you end up with the result being zero, as this is how you
initialized the variable `ans`.

I suggest two changes to your program:

1. Make the ranges wider
2. Repeatedly read the analog input *until* you get a valid reading.

To illustrate the second item, here is a code snippet that splits the
logic of you `if` chain in two parts: first read the operator
(repeatedly until we get a valid reading), then perform the operation:

```cpp
// Read the operator.
char op = ' ';  // space = no operator read so far
do {
    int val = analogRead(A0);
    if (val == 0) op = '+';
    if (val >= 97 && val <= 98) op = '*';
    if (val >= 253 && val <= 254) op = '/';
    if (val >= 407 && val <= 408) op = '-';
} while (op == ' ');

// Perform the operation.
switch (op) {
    case '+': ans = num1 + num2; break;
    case '*': ans = num1 * num2; break;
    case '/': ans = num1 / num2; break;
    case '-': ans = num1 - num2; break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear explanation. I fully agree that I was getting 0 occasionally due to circuit instability. I didn't know about do... while loops but now I do :) The program should have worked now but mysteriously the "ans" variable is not being updated by switch case. I tried it with if statements but it also doesn't work. I wonder what's causing this? P.s. I have uploaded the modified code in the original post.

Comment: @Zaffresky: Oops, my bad! The `switch` should be done on the selected operator, not on the analog value. I just edited the answer.

Comment: Bingo. It works nicely :) Thanks